# setdiff of rows in R

Tags: r

For two dataframes `df.1` and `df.2`, I want to know the rows of `df.1` that are not in `df.2`, i.e. rows that have disappeared or changed. 
Here is the example:

```
df.1 = cbind.data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 2:5, c = 99:102)
> df.1
  a b   c
1 1 2  99
2 2 3 100
3 3 4 101
4 4 5 102

df.2 = cbind.data.frame(a = c(1:3,7), b = c(3,3:4,9), c=c(99:100, 102, 105))
> df.2
  a b   c
1 1 3  99
2 2 3 100
3 3 4 102
4 7 9 105
```

So here my desired output is rows 1,3 and 4 of `df.1`:

```
> desired.output
  a b   c
1 1 2  99
3 3 4 101
4 4 5 102
```

If `df.1` and `df.2` were vectors I could use `setdiff(df.1, df.2)` but I don't see an easy/elegant way to apply this to dataframes.

Is there something more elegant than these workarounds I thought of:

- comparing `df.1` and `df.2` column by column and then taking the union from all columns
- making the dataframes a list of all of their rows, then use `setdiff` and convert back to dataframe

Comment: I feel like this is a major dupe. Usualy the most popular answer on these is `library(dplyr); anti_join(df.1, df.2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think , the most elegant(syntax sugar and very efficient) is using `data.table` package :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df.1)[!df.2, on = names(df.1)]
#    a b   c
# 1: 1 2  99
# 2: 3 4 101
# 3: 4 5 102
```

Note that this is different of :

```
setDT(df.2)[!df.1, on = names(df.2)]
#    a b   c
# 1: 1 3  99
# 2: 3 4 102
# 3: 7 9 105
```

Comment: Maybe just `setDT(df.1)[!df.2, on = names(df.1)]`. You don't need to key anymore in V 1.9.6+. Neither you need them both to be `data.table`s

Comment: @DavidArenburg Interesting. I will update my answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg this is alttile bit confusing on the sense that the one the table (the keys ) don't need to be a data.table here!

Comment: Yeah, this is an old feature though (I believe). I've been using this for the past year (at least).

Answer (score 5):

It is convenient to use anti_join in dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df.1,df.2)
Joining by: c("a", "b", "c")
  a b   c
1 1 2  99
2 4 5 102
3 3 4 101
```

Comment: This needs `setDT` otherwise I get the error: `Error in data.table::setkeyv(y, by$x) : x is not a data.table`

Comment: Try it on a clean data set (not on a `data.table`).

Comment: @DavidArenburg true, it works on a clean data set, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT * FROM [df.1] EXCEPT SELECT * FROM [df.2]')
```

Output:

```
  a b   c
1 1 2  99
2 3 4 101
3 4 5 102
```